# Writing Media Queries to Selectively Load Images Depending on Screen Size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following code from the carousel bootstrap template:

```
 64     <!-- Carousel
 65     ================================================== -->
 66     <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 67       <!-- Indicators -->
 68       <ol class="carousel-indicators">
 69         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
 70         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
 71         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 72       </ol>
 73       <div class="carousel-inner">
 74         <div class="item active">
 75           <img src="assets/images/outside/lake2.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" alt="">
 76           <div class="container">
 77             <div class="carousel-caption">
 78               <h1>escape the city</h1>
 79               <p></p>
 80               <!--<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Inquire today</a></p>-->
 81             </div>
 82           </div>
 83         </div>
 84         <div class="item">
 85           <img src="assets/images/outside/dock1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" alt="">
 86           <div class="container">
 87             <div class="carousel-caption">
 88               <h1>sit back and relax</h1>
 89               <p></p>
 90               <!--<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>-->
 91             </div>
 92           </div>
 93         </div>
 94         <div class="item">
 95           <img src="assets/images/outside/front2.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" alt="">
 96           <div class="container">
 97             <div class="carousel-caption">
 98               <h1>Welcome to the test site</h1>
 99               <p></p>
100               <!--<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">push me</a></p>-->
101             </div>
102           </div>
103         </div>
104       </div>
105       <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class=    "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
106       <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class    ="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
107     </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

I would like to know how I can create a separate css that will allow me do to media queries, and depending on the size of the device, change the images referenced in the above code to one that is smaller / bigger depending on need. 
So for example, I use the image:

```
<img src="assets/images/outside/dock1.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" alt="">
```

I am planning on creating several versions of that image like so:

- dock1_400px.jpg
- dock1_600px.jpg
- etc.

As the device changes or as the user changes the size of their browser, I would like to select a different version of the dock1 jpg file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Or, if there's an easier way to do this without creating multiple files for each image, I would like to know. 
Thanks!

**Edit 1**

I've tried to change the code for one of the images as a test ... like so:

```
 94         <div class="item"><div class="testclass"></div>
 95           <!--<img src="assets/images/outside/front2.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" alt="">-->
 96           <div class="container">
 97             <div class="carousel-caption">
 98               <h1>Welcome to the test site</h1>
 99               <p></p>
100               <!--<p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">push me</a></p>-->
101             </div>
102           </div>
103         </div>
```

As you can see I have commented out the image, and added a div with class value of "testclass".  This is what testclass looks like:

```
.testclass{
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(assets/images/outside/front2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position-x: center;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.  No image shows up.
Checking the F12 developer tool to see what I can find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an interesting article related to your question:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/images/images-in-css?hl=en

Here's an example:

```
.example {
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(small.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position-x: center;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .example {
    background-image: url(large.png);
  }
}
```

This example will load large.png image on screens that have a width greater than 500px.

You can do something similar with JavaScript (you can use JavaScript to selectively load images depending on the viewport size/ratio). For more information on this see the bottom of this page under the heading 'JavaScript Image Replacement': https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/images/images-in-markup?hl=en

Comment: if I add this type of a css, then what does the actual image tag in the main html file look like?

Comment: If you use this type of css you don't need an `img` tag in html. You'll simply use the `<div class="example"></div>` which will have the image as it's background.

Comment: Alternatively - see the use of the `picture` element on this page: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/images/images-in-markup?hl=en

Comment: i will post another question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use JavaScript if you want to change the images depending on viewport size.
Or you could also use [srcset](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/), but you'll probably need polyfill it.